# How can I import data downloaded from Kaggle to DBFS using Databricks Community Edition?

Tags: databricks, kaggle, databricks-community-edition

I managed to download datasets from Kaggle using Kaggle API. And the data was stored under the directory of /databricks/driver.

```
%sh pip install kaggle
%sh
export KAGGLE_USERNAME=my_name
export KAGGLE_KEY=my_key
kaggle competitions download -c ncaaw-march-mania-2021
%sh unzip ncaaw-march-mania-2021.zip
```

The problem is: How can I use them in DBFS? The following is how I read data and the error I got when I tried to use pyspark to read csv files:

```
spark.read.csv('/databricks/driver/WDataFiles_Stage1/Cities.csv')
AnalysisException: Path does not exist: dbfs:/databricks/driver/WDataFiles_Stage1/Cities.csv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`spark.read...` works with DBFS paths by default, so you have two choices:

- use `file:/databricks/driver/...` to force reading from the local file system - it will work on the community edition because it's single node cluster. It won't work on the distributed cluster
- copy files to DBFS using the `dbutils.fs.cp` command ([docs](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#file-system-utility-dbutilsfs)) and read from DBFS:

```py
dbutils.fs.cp("file:/databricks/driver/WDataFiles_Stage1/Cities.csv", 
   "/FileStore/Cities.csv")
df = spark.read.csv("/FileStore/Cities.csv")
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I have really struggled with the Kaggle API so I use `opendatasets`. I installed my libraries on the cluster.
[image]

```py
    import opendatasets as od
    
    od.download("https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/tlvmc-parkinsons-freezing-gait-prediction/data","/dbfs/FileStore/mypath/")
```

The output, when running this, shows first the zip being downloaded. Once the download is complete, it automatically extracts or unzips the files.

`Extracting archive /dbfs/FileStore/mypath/tlvmc-parkinsons-freezing-gait-prediction/tlvmc-parkinsons-freezing-gait-prediction.zip to /dbfs/FileStore/mypath/tlvmc-parkinsons-freezing-gait-prediction`

[documentation](https://pypi.org/project/opendatasets/)